# Render the column header in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to render the column header in a datatables cell. So far I am using columnDefs to adjust the contents of a cell, and I wish to add the column header or title:

```
"columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": [6], "render": function (data, type, column) {
        return '?continent='+column[1]+'?filter='+this.header;
     }
}]
```

I have been able to return the column header in the console or as an alert:
(https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().header())

but not as text in the cell

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/3481/
I would like the header of column 1 - Position - to be inserted into the link where I have written Col1header. Result for row 1 would look like: "tom.html?office=Tokyo?filter=Position"

Comment: what exactly u want to show? craete jsfiddle to and add proper datatable code

Comment: Thanks, added a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/bKEPNe

This is columnDefs code which i have changed

```
"columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": [1], 
    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var title = $('#example').DataTable().columns( meta.col ).header(); 
        var columnName = $(title).html();
        var url = 'tom.html?office='+row[2]+'?filter='+columnName.toLowerCase();
       return '<a href="'+url.trim()+'">'+data+'</a>';
     }
}]
```

Also, added  **"deferRender": true,** which will render once dataloaded

Comment: thanks, I had tried to do this but with no success, working now